# Can't run python - AttributeError: 'sys.flags' object has no attribute 'utf8_mode'

Tags: python, conda, attributeerror, miniconda

I created a conda environment with user1 and now trying to use it with user2 on a Ubuntu machine. I run:

```
conda activate /path/to/env
```

Activation seems to work OK, but when I try to run python I get:

```
$ python
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/powerapps/share/miniconda3-4.7.12/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 586, in <module>
    main()
  File "/powerapps/share/miniconda3-4.7.12/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 573, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/powerapps/share/miniconda3-4.7.12/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 349, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/powerapps/share/miniconda3-4.7.12/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 207, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "/powerapps/share/miniconda3-4.7.12/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 159, in addpackage
    f = open(fullname, "r")
  File "/powerapps/share/miniconda3-4.7.12/lib/python3.7/_bootlocale.py", line 35, in getpreferredencoding
    if sys.flags.utf8_mode:
AttributeError: 'sys.flags' object has no attribute 'utf8_mode'
```

With user1 (that created the env), everything works fine.
Also, if I do `conda deactivate` with user2, python runs fine.
When I run `which python`, with both users I get `/path/to/env/bin/python`.
The env recipe contains the dependency "python=3" (along with others), and the version that was actually installed is 3.6.10.

I understand that this has to do with some python2/3 incompatibility, but I don't understand why this  is happenning. Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: can you add the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`